# Alignment Issue with Stacked multiple Y Axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to implement multiple Y Axis, which will be arranged one upon the other like Stack. I am able to do that using top position in highchart. But the alignment of those Axis seems to be broken. I want all the axis to be aligned and inline with the first axis I have highlighted in Yellow in below snap
[image: Expected result]

I have created the fiddle for same, please let me know how do I do it, currently I tried with setting x position of Y axis label.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/priyankamore/churfL0p/  Fiddler example

Comment: I think that you can use labels.reserveSpace and offset parameters of your yAxis: https://jsfiddle.net/churfL0p/2/

Comment: Thanks alot @GrzegorzBlachliński